# Ubuntu 17.04 Server install w/2 drives

Tags: server, ssd, 17.04, partitioning

I am getting ready to install Ubuntu Server on a fresh build..  I bought a Samsung EVO 960 500GB M.2 drive and also a Crucial 1TB SSD drive..

Wondering what is the best way to partition these drives..  A friend said I should use the slower SSD drive for the OS and the 500GB M.2 for storage?

The machine has 64GB of RAM and a AMD Ryzen 7 1800X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the exact opposite.
Although with 64GB of RAM you probably won't notice the difference.
64GB plus good tmp/swap space and that PC of yours will be screaming fast.
You could do a RAM Disk on the partition as well and that would boost performance as well. You have plenty of RAM to do that and a lot to spare.

Comment: I plan to use this as a tile server for OSM..  I will research the swap and RAM disk options.. :)